# Trying to get property of non-object - Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

When I am trying to view a page on my application, I get the error

> Trying to get property of non-object on line 38 on StatController.php

Researching, this error means trying to get an object or data which doesn't exist.(**stand to be correccted**).

But my issue is, contact page (to view contacts) doesn't show an error even though contact table is also empty when the application's database is without any data.

What could be causing this error when I try to access the home page when a new user logs in?

**StatController**

```
public function home(Request $request) 
{
     $surveys = Survey::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->first();
     $respondent = Invite::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('survey_id', $surveys->id)->count();
     $answers = Invite::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('link_answered', 1)->where('survey_id', $surveys->id)->count();
     $yet_to_respond = Invite::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('link_clicked', 1)->where('survey_id', $surveys->id)->count();
     $no_response = Invite::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('link_clicked', 0)->where('survey_id', $surveys->id)->count();

     return view('home', compact('surveys','respondent','yet_to_respond','no_response','answers'));
}
```

**ContactController**

```
public function index()
{
    $contacts = Contact::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
    return view('contact.index',compact('contact'));
}
```

Comment: Which one is the line 38 of your controller?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz,  `$respondent = Invite::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('survey_id', $surveys->id)->count();`

Comment: @
LearnLaravel try to print_r($surveys);

Comment: This error for those users who don't have `Survey`

Comment: `$surveys` will be null if there aren't any surveys for the authenticated user. Check for null before retrieving the respondents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `$surveys` is coming back null so you must check it before accessing some property:

```
public function home(Request $request) 
{
    $respondent = null;
    $answers = null;
    $yet_to_respond = null;
    $no_response = null;

    $surveys = Survey::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->first();
    if($surveys){
        $respondent = Invite::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('survey_id', $surveys->id)->count();
        $answers = Invite::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('link_answered', 1)->where('survey_id', $surveys->id)->count();
        $yet_to_respond = Invite::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('link_clicked', 1)->where('survey_id', $surveys->id)->count();
        $no_response = Invite::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('link_clicked', 0)->where('survey_id', $surveys->id)->count();     
    }

    return view('home', compact('surveys','respondent','yet_to_respond','no_response','answers'));
}
```

Another way is to use [optional()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-optional) method and instead using `$surveys->id` you would be using `optional($surveys)->id`

> The optional function accepts any argument and allows you to access properties or call methods on that object. If the given object is null, properties and methods will return null instead of causing an error:

Comment: I think you are right. Also he can improve code quality by using relations

Comment: Yes, It would be a lot easier but I think he is just starting to learn laravel and might not know relations yet

Comment: optional is usefull this becomes my weakness when i forget to check if its an object or not

Answer (score 1):

As @Luis given you the right answer, This is another way to improve your code, call `Invite` one time and then filter out.

```
public function home(Request $request) 
{
     $surveys = Survey::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->first();
     $invites = collect([]);
     if($surveys){
        $invites = Invite::where('user_id', \Auth::id())->get();
     }
     $respondent = $invites->where('survey_id', $surveys->id ?? 0)->count();
     $answers = $invites->where('link_answered', 1)->where('survey_id', $surveys->id ?? 0)->count();
     $yet_to_respond = $invites->where('link_clicked', 1)->where('survey_id', $surveys->id ?? 0)->count();
     $no_response = $invites->where('link_clicked', 0)->where('survey_id', $surveys->id ?? 0)->count();
     return view('home', compact('surveys','respondent','yet_to_respond','no_response','answers'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Luis mentioned the error is because you are trying to access a property on `null` as `first` method will return `null` if no record is found.

One way is as @Luis mentioned in their answer to check for null or use `optional` helper

To add to his answer following is on how to achieve the same using `Eloquent`

## Using relations

In your `Survey` model add the following relations

```
public function invitations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Invite::class);
}

public function responded()
{
    return $this->invitations()
                ->where('link_answered', 1);
}

public function pending()
{
    return $this->invitations()
                ->where('link_clicked', 1);
}

public function unseen()
{
    return $this->invitations()
                ->where('link_clicked', 0);
}
```

And in your `StatController`

```
public function home(Request $request) 
{
    $survey = Survey::withCount(['invitations', 'responded', 'pending', 'unseen'])
                    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                    ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
                    ->first();
    return view('home', compact('survey'));
}
```

Then in your view you can get the count using

```
Invitations count: {{ $survey->invitations_count }}
Responded count: {{ $survey->responded_count }}
Pending count: {{ $survey->pending_count }}
Unseen count: {{ $survey->unseen_count }}
```

Also if your prefer you can clean up your existing code a little bit.

```
public function home(Request $request)
{
    $respondent = 0;
    $answers = 0;
    $yet_to_respond = 0;
    $no_response = 0;

    $survey = Survey::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                    ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->first();

    if ($survey) {
        $invitationQuery = Invite::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                                 ->where('survey_id', $survey->id);

        $respondent = $invitationQuery->count();
        $answers = with(clone $invitationQuery)->where('link_answered', 1)
                                               ->count();
        $yet_to_respond = with(clone $invitationQuery)->where('link_clicked', 1)
                                                      ->count();
        $no_response = with(clone $invitationQuery)->where('link_clicked', 0)
                                                   ->count();
    }

    return view('home', compact('survey','respondent','yet_to_respond','no_response','answers'));
}
```

Comment: This is great approach.